# Jasmine testing with Phantom js

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I wrote the Jasmine test for the javascript. I am trying to run the Jasmine tests using Phantomjs. I downloaded the Phantomjs from Phantomjs.org and tried running it using phantomjs.exe //path to phantom jasmine http://localhost/myJasmineTestRunner.html. Googling doesn't help me out. Can someone suggest me how to test jasmine tests using phantomjs.

Answer (score 2):

> **Running the Tests**
>
> In order to run our jasmine test suite on the command line, all we need is:
>
> - **PhantomJS**
>     Installing PhantomJS from phantomjs.org is fairly trivial (at least on a mac).
> - **A URL to our Jasmine test suite**
>     [We already covered jasmine test suites](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/testing-backbone-requirejs-applications-with-jasmine/), so we have a URL to a jasmine test suite.
> - **A script that loads our URL and parses the results**
>     Fortunately, PhantomJS provides a working [jasmine runner example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-jasmine.js) – all we have to do is [download](https://raw.github.com/ariya/phantomjs/master/examples/run-jasmine.js) it and use it.
>
> Once we got these, all we have to do is run the following command:
>   phantomjs 
>   It doesn’t take more than a few seconds(!) and we are provided with the test results.
>
> This is it.
>   Now, lets run it with our build tool.
>
> * For the purpose of this article, lets assume PhantomJS is installed on the system, our jasmine runner is located at /path/to/run-jasmine.js and our jasmine test suite is located at http://localhost/js/test/unit/

[Source](http://kilon.org/blog/2013/01/running-jasmine-tests-with-phantomjs/).